# Getting the time at which the latest record was submitted SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to fetch the time at which the latest record was made by a particular user.

Say there are 4 rows made by a user containing their distinct ID, called `steamid`. They were all made at different times. I would like to get the time at which the latest one was made.

[image: The table]

So to select the bottom record I tried.

```
$time = "SELECT max(time) FROM bets WHERE steamid='$number'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$time);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $previous = $row["time"];
}
} else {
$previous = '0';
}
```

However a dump of `$previous` returns null.

Comment: You may want to add `php` tag.

Comment: submit is as an answer if you want, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the result there will be no column named `time` as you haven't given any alias to the result of `max(time)`

Change the query to this: `SELECT max(time) as time ...`